# SharePoint The My Site of <user name> is scheduled for deletion

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

In my email today I got the following:

> The My Site of  is scheduled for deletion. As their manager you are now the temporary owner of their site. This temporary ownership gives you access to the site to copy any business-related information you might need. To access the site use this URL: http://mysites.mycompany.com/personal/

I click on the link and I can see that there site is there. I do not want there site to be deleted at all what can I do.

When I search for the user using the PeopleSearchBoxEx web part the user comes up but when I click on there name I get the error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

User not found. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: User not found.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[SPException: User not found.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfilePropertyLoader.OnInit(EventArgs e) +4415
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +333
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +378
```

Any idea how I can stop this person from being "delete" and get there profile to work again?

Answer (score 2):

I experience the same error.

I changed the primary site collection admin to myself on this mysite and that worked. This message is coming from the primary site collection admin being the user that has been deleted.

Go to central admin > application management > site collection administrators and choose your mysite application and then your user site collection for this site.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user has already been deleted (possibly due to sync with AD) but not yet removed from the search index. You'll need to look into what caused the user to be removed.